# TargetType does not work on generated Controls?

Tags: wpf, styles

What I try to achieve is to set a style of a, on runtime generated, button automatically. So I would like to do it without using:

```
dirButton.Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("DirectoryStyle");
```

This is my style I defined in my App.xaml (I deleted the setters for display purposes):

```
<Style x:Key="DirectoryStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:DirectoryButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
 </Style>
```

The Button stated above is generated on start up and stands for one folder within a given directory.

```
Directory Button dirButton = new DirectoryButton();

dirButton.Click += directoryButton_Click;
// Here I could set the style with the first code segment
```

So in short:
Is there a way to make TargetType affect generated controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `x:Key` from the Style declaration to make it a default Style for the TargetType.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DirectoryButton}">
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I meant!